# Calculate the limit including binomial coefficients

Tags: calculus, limits, summation, binomial-coefficients

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\sum\limits_{k=n}^{5n}{k-1 \choose n-1}(\frac{1}{5})^{n}(\frac{4}{5})^{k-n}}$

It's clear that we can simplify the limit a little bit, after which we get:

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{(\frac{1}{4})^{n}\sum\limits_{k=n}^{5n}{k-1 \choose n-1}(\frac{4}{5})^{k}}$

I could further simplify the expression, but I feel like there's a more elegant solution.

Give me a hint, please

Comment: Since the sum equals $1$ if the upper limit is extended to infinity, and the $k=5n$ term is essentially the mode of the sequence being summed, my guess (supported by a little numerical experimentation) is that the answer is $1/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint for a probabilistic proof**: look at the negative binomial distribution as the sum of independent geometric distributions, and apply the central limit theorem.

Comment: Wow, this is definitely very elegant. Can you please elaborate on the solution approach a bit more? 

If I understand correctly, what we have here is a sum of $(4n+1)$ random variables with a negative binomial distribution, each of which is, in turn, a sum of geometric distributions. Is that correct?

Comment: For each of the $(4n+1)$ random variables, we can conclude that for large values of $n$ the negative binomial random variable can be represented by $N(0,1)$ for $ Z = \frac{Y_n-\mu}{\sigma} $, where $\mu = \frac{n}{p}$ and $\sigma = \sigma\sqrt{n}$. 
This is where I get lost. Can we proceed with $P(n\leq {Y}_n\leq {5n})$ and transform both sides to match the normally distributed $Z$?

Comment: I don't see where the $4n+1$ random variables come from.  Let $X_n\sim Geo(\frac15)$ (1-indexed), $Y_n=X_1+\dots+X_n$ and you want the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(\bar{Y}\leq 5)$.

Comment: Sorry for being stupid, but how do you get the last limit? We have $\mu_{n} = \frac{n}{p}=5n$, and $\sigma_{n}=2\sqrt{5n}$. 
We can now conclude that $Y_n \sim N(0,1)$, right?

Comment: In the previous comment, I meant $Z_n = \frac{Y_n-\mu_{n}}{\sigma_{n}}$, of course

Comment: We have $\mu_X=1/p=5$ and $\sigma^2_X=q/p^2=20$ so CLT gives $(\bar{Y}-5)/\sqrt{20/n}$ is asymptotically $N(0,1)$.  Hence $\mathbb{P}(\bar{Y}\leq 5)\sim\mathbb{P}(Z\leq 0)=\frac12$.

Comment: Everything seems perfectly clear except for one thing. Why are you considering $ \mathbb{P}(\hat{Y}\leq{5})$ from the very start?
I managed to get $\mathbb{P}(Z\leq {0})$, but I (probably, mistakenly) evaluated $\mathbb{P}({n\leq{Y}\leq{5n}})$

Comment: $Y\geq n$ is automatic for a negative binomial (recall we count number of trials, not number of failures, and it takes at least $n$ trials to get $n$ successes).

Comment: Okay, now it finally clicks. Thank you very much for your instructive help. Can you recommend any good textbooks where similar problems are first discussed or even solved with detailed explanations? It seems that I am still too far from an intuitive understanding of the CLT...

Answer (score 2):

Let $\left[x^j\right]f(x)$ denote the $x^j$ coefficient in $f(x)$. You seek$$\frac15\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left[x^{n-1}\right]\sum_{k=n}^{5n}\left(\frac{4+x}{5}\right)^{k-1}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[x^{n-1}\right]\frac{\left(\frac{4+x}{5}\right)^{n-1}-\left(\frac{4+x}{5}\right)^{5n}}{1-x}\\=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\left[x^j\right]\left(\left(\frac{4+x}{5}\right)^{n-1}-\left(\frac{4+x}{5}\right)^{5n}\right)=1-\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X<n|X\sim\text{Binom}(5n,\,\tfrac15))\\=1-\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X<n|X\sim N(n,\,\tfrac{4n}{5}))=\tfrac12.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using identify ${n\choose r} = \frac{n}{r}\cdot {{n-1} \choose {r-1}}$

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\sum\limits_{k=n}^{5n}{k-1 \choose n-1}(\frac{1}{5})^{n}(\frac{4}{5})^{k-n}}$$

= $$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\sum\limits_{k=n}^{5n} \frac{n}{k}{k \choose n}(\frac{1}{5})^{n}(\frac{4}{5})^{k-n}} $$.

Now, Divide both sides in the expansion of $(1+x)^n=nC0+nC1 x+...+nCn x^n$ by x and integrate both sides from 0 to 1. 
Substitute the identity in the limit expression and evaluate it.